# MySQL delay in Relay Master log file

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, database-replication

We are facing a serious issue of time lagging in mysql database. We have two databases on different location which gets replicated (both are master and slave) there are 3 Relay log files(each 100 MB) which got transferred on Slave server but it is taking almost 5 hours to process each log file. What might be the reason? This is happening for the last one day only previously it was working fine.Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Top command:
[image]

Show slave status

Slave_IO_State:     [read blank]
Master_Host : Master IP address
Master_User: replication
Master_Port: 3306
Connect_Retry:  60
Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000430
Read_Master_Log_Pos: 48495450
Relay_Log_File:mysqld-relay-bin.000008
Relay_Log_Pos:65771774
Relay_Master_Log_File:mysql-bin.000427
Slave_IO_Running:No
Slave_SQL_Running:Yes
Exec_Master_Log_Pos:65771611
Relay_Log_Space:363072212
Until_Condition:None
Seconds_Behind_Master:109300

Comment: Did replication break? What is status of both slave io thread and SQL thread?  Can you show `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` query results in your question?

Comment: No Replication did not break. We have stopped couple of time but they were normal. I have updated the question please let me know if you want more details.

Comment: The slave io is not running, so it seems that replication did in fact break (or stop at least).  The slave SQL is running, but since there are no new binary logs coming in, it is not doing anything.  Try `START SLAVE IO_THREAD` to see if you can restart it.

Comment: In order to clear backlog binary files,we have stopped the further processing of any data from Slave thats why it is showing No.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "clear backlog binary files".  In this case it looks like your slave SQL thread is inactive, just waiting for new binlogs to be sent to it.

Comment: I meant in Relay_Master_Log_File:mysql-bin.000427 needs to finish. We have mysql-bin.000426, mysql-bin.000427, mysql-bin.000428, mysql-bin.000429 binlogs from Master server. the first file mysql-bin.000426 got executed in 5 hours (this got executed by putting slave io off).Now the next mysql-bin.000427 is processing. The counter Relay_Log_Pos:65771774 on each refresh keeps on increasing

Comment: OK.  SO you are actively pefrorming SQL on slave, you are just not caught up there.  It is really hard to say what may have changed.  Did you have a change in call pattern on master that suddenly created a lot more binlog entries?

Comment: No we did not notice any change pattern on Master. there were network issue for one day and it all got jumbled up on that day.